# Java Symbol Error

Tags: java

i keep getting this "Error:cannot find symbol" on line 44 and i cant figure out what symbol im missing. im sure that all my variables are declared. Can someone help me find the problem in my code?

```
class personne{
    private String naissance;
    private int nbCafe;

    public personne(String year, int number){
        naissance=year;
        nbCafe=number;
    }
    public personne(String year){
        naissance=year;
        nbCafe=1;
    }

    public String getnaissance(){
        return naissance;
    }
    public int getnbCafe(){
        return nbCafe;
    }
    public void afficher(String message){
        System.out.println(message+ ": nee le 16 novembre 1994, consomme 2 tasse(s) de cafe");
    }

    public void affichertable(personne [] table, int amount,String message){
        System.out.printf("Contenu du tableau de %d personne(s) %s", amount,message);
            System.out.printf("Naissance     nbCafe");
        for (int i=0; i<amount;i++)
            System.out.printf("%6.2s    %8.2d\n", table[i].getnaissance(), table[i].getnbCafe() );


    }
}

public class popo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        personne p1= new personne("16/11/1994",2);
        personne p2=new personne("15/12/1990");

        p1.afficher("Informations de p1");

        personne[] pers={ new personne("12/10/1991",3),new personne("15/10/1990",6), new personne("13/07/1993",3), new personne("05/06/1991"),new personne("16/12/1992",3)};    
        int nbpers=pers.length;

        affichertable(pers,nbpers,"premier tableau");//This is line 44 where the error occurs
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message tells you which symbol. In this case, that is `affichertable` which is not declared in `popo`.

Comment: And please respect naming conventions.

Comment: But isnt that method already declared in the class? and im basically just calling it in main?

Comment: @user3268216: No, you've got two different classes here - `popo` (containing `main`) and `personne` (containing `affichertable`). The fact that they're declared in the same source file is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`affichertable` is an instance method in `personne`. You're trying to call it as if it's a static method in `popo`.

You should be calling `p1.affirchertable(...)` or `p2.affichertable(...)` at a guess.

Alternatively, if the `affirchertable` method isn't *meant* to depend on the state of a single instance of `personne`, you should change it to a static method, and call it as:

```
personne.affichertable(...);
```

(As an aside, I'd *strongly* advise you to follow normal Java naming conventions and capitalize your class names - and put different classes in different source files.)

Comment: thx i tried the personne.affichertable and it seems to work but have some difficulties printing the table "Error:non-static method". Yes my teacher told me about how programmer will hate me if i dont capitalize my class names and what not.

Comment: @user3268216: Well it's *not* working if you're getting an error - you need to make it a static method (as I described in my answer).

Comment: Yes i did that but it keeps displaying this weird long texts:Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 2
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkInteger(Formatter.java:2936)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2684)
 at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2528)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2469)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
 at popo.affichertable(popo.java:34)
 at popo.demo2(popo.java:44)
 at popo.main(popo.java:54)